# C++ linker finds header but cannot find .cpp file (using cmake, gcc)

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I am trying to include a project within a project.
The relevant structure is as such:

```
projectA
       /CMakeLists.txt (PA1)
       /src
           /main.cpp
       /req/projectB
                   /CMakeLists.txt (PB1)
                   /src
                       /projb.hpp
                       /projb.cpp
                       /CMakeLists.txt (PB2)
```

After compiling, linking SUCCEEDS if I comment out everything in projb.cpp, (and define it in the header) but FAILS with undefined reference (to any function defined in projb.cpp).

-(PA1)-

```
add_subdirectory("req/projectB")

include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} "req/projectB/src")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE projectB)
```

-(PB1)-

```
add_subdirectory(src)
```

-(PB2)-

```
add_library(projectB projb.hpp projb.cpp)
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    project_b::doStuff();
    return 1;
}
```

projb.hpp

```
namespace project_b {

    void doStuff(); // fails
    
    void doStuff() {} // works if nothing defined in .cpp
    // (only one or the other version is declared not both)

} // end namespace
```

projb.cpp

```
namespace project_b {
    
    void doStuff() {} // fails with undefined reference error when called from main

} // end namespace
```

Comment: A linker doesn't look at .cpp files at all. Run `make VERBOSE=1` to see actual compilation commands.

Comment: that's how I've been running make

Comment: This is not apparent from your post. If `projb.cpp` is not compiled, why is it surprising that stuff defined in it is undefined?

Comment: when I check in the build folder, the libs for projectB are there.

Comment: But they are not used for building the executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that another part of projectA which I thought was irrelevant was actually very relevant.

Thus I just needed to add this line:

```
# projAadep is included by main.cpp from projectA
target_link_libraries(projAdep PRIVATE projectB)
```

before this line:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC projectB)
```

My understanding was that by using:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} list of all used libs here)
```

was all that is necessary.

How discovered this was when I was commenting out various things in order to get the output of `make VERBOSE=1` to just include the most relevent parts, it compiled and linked successfully. This then led me to do more testing to figure out why it linked successfully, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> Libraries following INTERFACE are appended to the link interface and are not used for linking .

see: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html

So, I suggest changing INTERFACE to PUBLIC or PRIVATE

Comment: tried using PUBLIC and PRIVATE, still doesn't work

Comment: @R.Smyth Works for me, perhaps uncomment projb.cpp?

Comment: it is. still fails.

Comment: @R.Smyth please post the complete output of `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: Also,  delete `CMakeCache.txt` and do `make clean` before building.

Comment: I created a directory tree like yours, with an appropriate `CMakeLists.txt` header and `#include`s in source files. After commenting out a function definition in  `projb.hpp` and replacing INTERFACE with PUBLIC, one only needs to create a build directory, `mkdir build`, `cd build`, `cmake ..`,  `make` and voila, everything compiles just fine.